# Custom Page Slug with multiple query strings using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following line in my .htaccess file to create custom page stubs

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?slug=$1 [QSA]
```

So basically this turns **my-site.com/my-fancy-url** into **my-site.com/index.php?slug=my-fancy-site**

I need to add an additional variable onto the query string like this:

**my-site.com/index.php?slug=my-fancy-site&customId=5**

So I can use this URL:

**my-site.com/my-fancy-url/5**

Any ideas how I would alter the Rewrite rule to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?slug=$1&customId=$2 [QSA]
```